# Laravel 5.4 - File Storage returns false when checking for file existence

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, php-7.0

I am trying to see if a file exist in the storage folder. It returns false in the server even if the file exist. In my local environment, it is working perfect.

I am trying to store avatar for users. When I check if avatar exists, it returns false.

Store avatar:

```
    $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
    $user   = Auth::user();

    if($avatar && $file = $avatar->isValid()) {
        $file = $request->file('avatar');
        $path = $user->avatar_path;
        $image = Image::make($file)->fit(100,100)->encode('jpg');
        Storage::put($path, $image);

        $url = Storage::url($path);
    }
```

Checking for avatar existence

```
    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($user->has_avatar) {
        Storage::delete($user->avatar_path);
    }
```

has avatar method in user.php model

```
public function getHasAvatarAttribute()
{
    return Storage::disk('public')->has('avatars/'.md5($this->id . $this->email).'.jpg');
}
```

Avatar path function

```
public function getAvatarPathAttribute()
{
    return 'public/avatars/'. md5($this->id . $this->email) . '.jpg';
}
```

When I test on my machine, all is good. On server, it returns false even if avatar exists.

Comment: What is the sample value for ```$user->avatar_path```

Comment: I have updated mu question with $user->avatar_path. Sample is public/avatars/02d15eeccb15093f05215a4a38b84.jpg

Comment: Can you clarify that your default disk is ```public```? Because it seems you are using ```Storage::disk('public')``` to check but you didnt specify public disk when you store.

Comment: Yes, it is public.

Comment: Working now. My default is set to public, but this worked after I manually called disk('public') in each of my method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not comment Yet so I will leave this answer here. In production it is not working? As in a live server? Maybe linux server? And you are running the local development on Windows? See where I am going with this? Your path maybe wrong. I mean the naming. Even `a` to `A` or vice versa may effect the path. The same goes for your file naming. And path naming. `avatar/something` and `/avatar/something` are completely different.

Please let me know if that was the case.

Comment: yes, working on production which is GNU/Linux 9 and my local development is on the same as well. There is no issue with the path

Comment: Do you have access to the directory? You are using Storage and I’m assuming it’s going to public folder. Did you create a symlink? `php artisan Storage:link`. And give it read/write permission. That maybe causing this

Comment: yes, I did create a symlink. Permissions are given as well. avatar Image in fact is being uploaded by the user.

Comment: I need some more details. Are you using the same server for dev and production? And what is `has_avatar`. How is it looking like? If you are using 2 different servers, are the versions same on php, apache/nginx etc?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed the updated question. Did you try manually putting your image file name? Can you please copy and paste this code in your has attribute in user.php to see if it will work. `return Storage::disk('public')->has('avatars/02d15eeccb15093f05215a4a38b84.jpg');` Note: Please put the name of a file that exists

Comment: Worked after I mentioned disk soecifically in each of my methods